# Is it possible to handle tap events on a column of BarChart?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I know that on `MPAndroidChart` is possible to handle events on the charts. On its [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart) are all well documented.

Nevertheless I am not able to find any documentation about the same events on `ios-chart`. I know that its creator tells that we should follow the documentaiton of `MPAndroidChart` for his library also but I am not able to handle that events on Swift 3.0.

I also could not find any examples handle these events for `ios-chart` library.

so, Is it possible to handle tap event on `ios-chart` library?

**EDIT:** According to the feedback of `@AdamM` I am going to put here the function in which I set the data to the chart.

```
func enterData(valuesChart: [BarChartDataEntry]){
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: valuesChart, label: "Total Values")

    let charData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])
    barChartView?.data = charData
    barChartView?.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not ask the authors?

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I have followed the steps on `Questions & Issues` section: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts#questions--issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, this functionality is built in to the charting library. Make sure your class conforms to the ChartViewDelegate protocol.

Edit full code sample

```
import UIKit
import Charts

@objc(BarChartFormatter)
public class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter
{
    var months: [String]! = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        return months[Int(value)]
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController,ChartViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var barChart : BarChartView!
     let dataArray = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.title = "Testing"

        let values = [5.2,10.5,15.3]
        setBarChart(values: values)
        barChart.delegate = self
    }

    //MARK: Chart delegate methods
    func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {

        let pos = NSInteger(entry.x)
        print(dataArray[pos])
    }

    func chartValueNothingSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase)
    {

    }
    //MARK: Set chart
    func setBarChart(values: [Double])
    {
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<values.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])

            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
        var dataSets : [IChartDataSet] = [IChartDataSet]()
        dataSets.append(dataSet)

        let format:BarChartFormatter = BarChartFormatter()
        let xAxis = barChart.xAxis
        xAxis.granularity = 1.0
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.valueFormatter = format


        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        barChart?.data = chartData

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AdamM, Thank you for answer but I am not able to make it to work. Where should I add `barChart?.delegate = self`. Anything inside these functions does not seem to be executed after I click on any column of my CombinedChart.

Comment: Check edit. If you have any more issues, I can put up complete code sample tomorrow morning when I have my macbook again

Comment: I will try tomorrow when I will have my macbook again also and I will reply you  if it worked or not. Thank you again :)

Comment: Ok I have tried it but it only works for the method `chartValueNothingSelected` when I make double click (select the column and deselect it) but it never enters when I tap the column (1 click) on the method `chartValueSelected`.

Comment: Updated my answer will full code sample. Just tested it there, seems to be working fine

Comment: Ok, the only thing that I have different with you is that I have a method `setChart()` in which I retrieve the data from a database with Alamofire. When it finish I call another method called `enterData(values)` in which I set the values to the chart but as I can see you also use a function to create the chart. Also, before you updated the answer, I had `@IBOutlet var barChart : BarChartView!` instead of `@IBOutlet var barChart : BarChartView?`. Now I have changed it but I do not know if it could be the problem but I do not think so. But I still cannot get tap event when the chart is clicked.

Comment: The ? or ! won't matter too much, that just means it is either wrapped or unwrapped value. Regardless of where you get the data, as long as you have the chart setup and assigned the delegate, it should work. Can you update your question with some source code so I can have a look?

Comment: Would it be helpful if I add all my code without how I retrieve the data? I mean, how the JSON comes to my program. For security reasons I cannot provide it online.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need to know about how you retrieve the code, I just want to see what you do with the data once you receive it.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have omitted the lines about the configuration of the chart like color, text-size, etc because I think it does not have anything related with the problem.

Comment: Ok see in that method there, after you have called that method, then call barChartView.delegate = self

Comment: So I call it two times? one on viewDidLoad and the other after executing that method from Alamofire?

Comment: I have tried it on both places and only one after calling that method but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Finally as the other user suggested the problem was the dataSetIndex.

Comment: You only need to call it once, after you have set the chart data, then set the delegate. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your code? I would need to see more of your source code to see what is wrong. Can you confirm you have setup the chart to allow user interaction? Does the chart highlight when you click it?

Comment: Now it works when I select the chart with the code provided by @user2986119 but the problem now is that I do not know how to access to the id of each column. And I cannot find any documentation about this method.

Comment: I just realized my version is out of date, give me 20 mins will update my code base, then update my answer

Comment: Updated answer with new code. I did not realize the chart library I was using was so out of date. The above code should work fine now and included code to show you how you would access ID of each column

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is what I wanted :). I will wait to give you the bounty until the last day of the bounty so you can get more rep if the users come to this question. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

For IOS Charts 3. Omit the dataSetIndex!

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) 
{...}
```

Comment: Yes, that is. The problem was the dataSetIndex! But now I have a doubt. How can I access to the column itself in which I tap??

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Finally @AdamM completed the code example.